# ZEO: How can I make lets clients in read-only but make changes through the console

Tags: plone

I'm running a script by pasting it in a console like this:

```
 bin/client2 debug

 ... my script ...
```

The script normalizes titles of the files. Since there are more than 20k files it takes *really* too much to time. So I need users still can use the site but in a read-only fashion.

But I assume that setting `read-only true` in `zeo.conf` would not let me run my normalization script. Wouldn't it?

How can I solve this?

Best regards,

Manuel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *isn't*, I'm afraid.

If your users alter the site when logged in, disable logging in for them until you are done.

Generally, for tasks like these, I run the changes in batches, to minimize conflicts and allow end-users to continue to use the site as normal. Break your work up in chunks, and commit after every n items processed.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another zeo client that is not RO--it's not required that a zeoserver be RO to have the clients RO.

So, all the clients that are being used, make RO, and then add an additional RW client that isn't used by anyone but your script and then leave the zeoserver RW.